# Failed to write core dump ulimit -c tried everything not working

Tags: java, coredump

I am trying to program a serial Connection but have a bug that I cannot solve.  I have tried `ulimit -c unlimited`. 
This is my outcome

```
$ root@kiriubu-ThinkPad-T510:~# ulimit -c 
$ root@kiriubu-ThinkPad-T510:~#unlimited


package de.kyrill.joystick;

public class ComTest{

    public static void main (String args []){
        TwoWaySerialComm TSC = new TwoWaySerialComm();
        try {
            TSC.connect("/dev/ttyUSB0");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I used this class http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Two_way_communcation_with_the_serial_port

this is my error code.

```
   SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4dddff2d9d, pid=16478, tid=0x00007f4dddeea700
   JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
   Problematic frame:
   C  [librxtxSerial.so+0x6d9d]  read_byte_array+0x3d
   Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, 
       try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again`
```

I run intellij as root. I have updated java. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
I have searched for an answer but I have found nothing that works. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you asking how to enable core dumps, or how to make your application work? What you are trying to do, `ulimit -c`, will only enable core dumps. Your application will still crash.